# update in Doctrine with special characters

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have this error when i try to update my value with special character

> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't' WHERE (idcommentaire = 117)' at line 1. Failing Query: "UPDATE commentaire SET commentaire = 'test't' WHERE (idcommentaire = 117)"

```
UPDATE commentaire SET commentaire = 'test't' WHERE (idcommentaire = 117)
                                          ^
```

Why doctrine does not manage special characters ?

> 

My function:

```
static public function modifierCommentaire($id, $commentaire)
{
    $req = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('Commentaire c')
    ->set('c.commentaire ', $commentaire)
    ->where("c.idcommentaire=$id")
    ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use prepared statements and an update query should look like something like this:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->update('Commentaire c')
  ->set('c.commentaire', '?', $commentaire)
  ->where('c.idcommentaire = ?', $id)
  ->execute();
```

So where you have a variable put a `?` there and pass the parameter as an argument. This way doctrine will create prepared statements and the variables will be escaped correctly (and it is more efficient too).